# Prevent UILocalNotifications when the app is killed

Tags: ios, xamarin, ibeacon

I have developed IBeacon App. When the app is in background mode and I enter the beacon region the UILocalNotification is triggered. But the thing is that if I kill the app the notification still triggers. I use `locationMgr.RequestAlwaysAuthorization ();` to catch the location change when the app is in background. I have written background-safe task to enlarge my background time on iPhone.

I have tried to use `UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationState` but it returns true when the app is in background only, not terminated.

I use `locationMgr.RequestAlwaysAuthorization ();` since `DidEnterRegion` is called only with location set to **ALWAYS**.

In a word I am searching for the solution how to monitor EnterRegion&ExitRegion only in background and active mode. **NOT WHEN THE APP IS KILLED**

Answer (score 2):

Before iOS 7.1 this was the default behavior of iOS, and everybody complained about it.  Since iOS 7.1, beacon monitoring will launch apps even if they are killed.

What you need is a way to detect if an app has previously been killed when it is launched again so you can suppress notifications.  Unfortunately, I am unaware of any way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons why an app would be terminated (not running):

- because the user actively terminated it (double-tap on home button, swipe app up)
- because the OS needed the memory, and terminated it
- because the OS updated the app, and terminated it
- because the device was rebooted, and the app was not launched yet

Do you want to avoid notifications in all cases, or only in the first one?

If you want to avoid notifications in all cases, you can try removing the local notification in your `AppDelegate`'s `applicationWillTerminate:` method (or an observer for the `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` notification):

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [application cancelLocalNotification:<insert here the notification you saved>];
}
```

(you may alternatively use `cancelAllLocalNotifications`, or search for the notification using `scheduledLocalNotifications`).

If you only want to avoid those notifications in the first case, I'm afraid I'm not aware of any way to detect the user having actively terminated the app.

Comment: I tried setting the static property to true in AppDelegate's `applicationWillTerminate` method and then checking it in my method if this property was true, but it was still false.Weird but, seems `applicationWillTerminate` is not called.

Comment: In what method? Called when? Unless you call it from `applicationWillTerminate`, it will of course never be true, as the application will have exited by then. You need to save it to some persistent storage (e.g. `NSUserDefaults`, a file, Core Data...). You can check if `applicationWillTerminate` is called by adding a log in there, and checking the device's logs. Note that if you stop the app from Xcode, the app is killed right away, and `applicationWillTerminate` will indeed never be called.

Comment: Note that `applicationWillTerminate` is **not** called if iOS terminates your app while it's not running, i.e., it's in the "suspended" state. And if it's not in the suspended state, i.e., is running in the background, iOS will be reluctant to terminate it anyway, unless it already terminated all the suspended apps and still needs more memory. *Long story short*, `applicationWillTerminate` is almost surely not an answer to your problem.